# Fullcalendar Friday events not rendering

Tags: fullcalendar

If I have 'weekends' set to false, Fullcalendar does not render any events entered on the Friday when viewing in my default view of agendaWeek. I have to switch to month view, then back to agendaWeek for them to render.

If I enable weekends, the Friday events show when my page is first loaded. However, I don't want weekends to show as I will never have any weekend events. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: What version of fullcalendar, jquery, [moment.js]? Are the events Friday-only or do they span multiple days? Do you have a minimal example of code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: It would help if you could make a jsfiddle reproducing the issue.

Comment: It will be easy if you provide fullcalendar's configuration options.